# sql count display number

Tags: php, html, mysql, codeigniter

Simple question:
I'm using Codeigniter and MySQL database.
I currently have a Table in my database named "profiles" to store each user's information.
Back on track, I need to display in an HTML table the number of users registered per location ('location' is one of the fields in my 'profiles' table).

I've tried this, so far: 
MODEL:

```
    function asia_count()
{
    $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM profiles WHERE location = 'Asia'";
    return $query;
}
```

CONTROLLER:

```
public function admin_m_reports_users_loc()
{
    $data['asia_count'] =$this->help_model->asia_count();
    $this->load->view('squidtopus1-admin-reports-users-location',$data);
}
```

VIEW:
(related line:)

```
    <tr>
  <td><a href="#">Asia</a></td>
  <td><?php echo $asia_count; ?></td>
  </tr>
```

In regards to the VIEW(related line), I need it to display as Asia | 1 (1 is example result)

...but I can't track down where I went wrong. Could someone please point me to the right direction?
Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You miss `result()` or `result_array()`. You can try this, use this code as your model.

```
function asia_count()
{
    $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) as Total FROM profiles WHERE location = 'Asia'";
    $result = $query->result_array();
    return $result[0]['Total'];
}
```

---

If you want list all location count you can try this

Model

```
function asia_count()
{
    $query = "SELECT location, COUNT(*) as Total FROM profiles GROUP BY location";
    return $query->result_array();
}
```

View

```
foreach ($lists as $index => $row) {
    echo $row['location'] . ':' . $row['Total'];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I edited the post for clarifications. I need to display the count() result on the webpage, that's my aim.

Comment: You want list all your location count?

Comment: Thanks for this. The query returns correctly, but do you think there's a way to just display the number result of COUNT(*)? Because I've already made a table on the webpage that has the corresponding countries listed already. All I need now is a way to retrieve the number produced by COUNT(*) and display that number on my table. Is it possible to do this?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean, can you give me a example?

Answer (score 1):

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM profiles WHERE location = 'Asia'");

if ($query->num_rows() > 0)
 {
$row = $query->row_array(); 
echo $row['COUNT(*)'];
}
```

Comment: @Leon Baños MAY THIS HELP YOU :)